# Nginx : Use a variable for proxy_read_timeout

Tags: nginx, timeout, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-upstreams

I would like to have a dynamic proxy_read_timeout.
But when I use a variable like this :

```
proxy_read_timeout $upstream_read_timeout;
```

I get this error :

> ```
>  "proxy_read_timeout" directive invalid value
> ```

I guess it means that proxy_read_timeout value cannot be defined though a variable.
Then how is it possible to have a dynamic timeout for upstreams ?

Is it not possible at all ?